# proving the existence of a real number c such that the function holds

Tags: real-analysis, functions, real-numbers

[image: J]

h: R—>R be a function
h(m+y)=h(m)+h(y)
h(0+0)=h(0)+h(0) –>h(0)=0
h(n)=h(1)+h(1)+...+h(1) (n times)
conclude that h(n)=n*h(1)

Since h(x)x*H(1)H(1)< H(1)y
hence H(t)=t*H(1)
so ∃ c∈R s.t. h(x)=c*x where c=H(1).

Comment: Try to be clearer please i dont understand the end, but i think you should consider defining your function on $\mathbb{Q}$ first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First verify that $h(nx)=nh(x)$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$ and $x$. [Proof similar to that of $h(n)=nh(1)$]. For a rational number $r=\frac p q$ note that $qf(rx)=f(rqx)=f(px)=pf(x)$ so we get $f(rx)=rf(x)$. Now let $x$ be any real number. Let $r$ and $s$ be rational numbers such that $r \leq x \leq s$. We get $f(r) \leq f(x) \leq f(s)$. Hence $rf(1) \leq f(x) \leq sf(1)$. Ler $r$ decrease to $x$ and $s$ increase to $x$. You get $f(x)=xf(1)$